# wit.ai runActions how to handle context in follow-up message

Tags: node.js, wit.ai

I'm using node-wit to develop a chatbot application.
This is working fine mostly, but I've run into a problem with the use of the context.

I'm using the runActions api :

```
       this.witClient.runActions(customer._key, messageText, witContext).then((newContext => {}
)).catch(reject);
```

I have defined a number of actions, which set the context.

This is working fine, as long the context is taking place over one message.
For example, if I were to call an action called addProduct :

```
addProduct({sessionId, context, text, entities}) {

                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                            context.product = `myNewProduct';
                            resolve(context);

                });
            },
```

It will then show a message using the 'product' context key.

However, when I try to use it over 2 messages, it seems to have lost the context ( for example, when asking a multiple choice question, and then handling that response ).

If I understand how it's working correctly, then node-wit doesn't keep the context beyond messages ( I assumed this at first because I'm passing a session key ).

A solution I see is to store the resulting context ( newContext in this case) in a session/user specific way, and then restore it and pass it again when the user is sending his new message.

Meaning, something like this :

witContext = getContextFromSession();
this.witClient.runActions(customer._key, messageText, witContext).then((newContext => { setContextInSession(newContext) }
    )).catch(reject);

Would this be the correct way of handling it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off course you have to store your context state, you decide how to store it. But, take into account what is the most efficient way if you're gonna have a lot of users, and your reasources available.

As you can see in the official example for nodeJs, there's a method named findOrCreateSession on https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit/blob/master/examples/messenger.js they get the session before the wit actions are called.

In my particular case, I am storing it in the database, so I get the session before the action is called, so I can send the context, then in the actions I query the session again to modify the resulting context and store it again, try the best implementation for your needs.